# Cannot convert type 'PhotonPlayer' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, transform

I think this code should work, but I get the following error message:

> cannot convert type 'PhotonPlayer' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Here is the code:

```
if (this.inputLine.StartsWith("/tpto"))
{
    PhotonPlayer player19 = PhotonPlayer.Find(Convert.ToInt32(this.inputLine.Remove(0, 5)));
    {
        ((GameObject)PhotonNetwork.player).transform.position = ((GameObject)player19).transform.position; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if it can't be converted, it can't be converted. It means the types aren't compatible. Without knowing more about Photon I'd be unable to help you. Are you sure the class type that `PhotonNetwork.player` is is inherited from GameObject?

Comment: I think no,,Is there no other way ? teleport to targeting player,,this code work but just teleport to random player in player list not targeting,,,,  https://pastebin.com/raw/Hn1pK0VP ,, I think I can convert Obj to photonplayer I wrong,, Im confused